# Azure DevOps ##[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: $\Data Warehouse\odl.datawarehouse

Tags: azure-devops

Our Azure Devops is getting an error started on 6-Oct-2022. This issue never happened before and I am writing to ask for your help.

I have used VS to change Stored Procedure on the local server and then did Check-in, an error at “Copy Files to:” step as below

(I have not changed anything since the last successful check-in)

Copy Files to: D:\a\8\a

View raw log
Starting: Copy Files to: D:\a\8\a
Task : Copy files
Description : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
Version : 2.209.0
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: $\Data Warehouse\odl.datawarehouse
Finishing: Copy Files to: D:\a\8\a

The SourceFolder still there as the screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: Usually，the error should be Not found SourceFolder:  `D:\a\8\a\s\$\Data Warehouse\odl.datawarehouse` .Maybe $/Data Warehouse/ is not needed. Did you have the folder $\Data Warehouse\odl.datawarehouse in your branch  $\Data Warehouse?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, I have removed /Data Warehouse and the issue still happened: ##[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\8\s\$\odl.datawarehouse.  I have the folder $/Data Warehouse/odl.datawarehouse in branch $/Data Warehouse. I have also tried to replace "/" with "\".